# Fetching packages works, but pushing results in access denied

Tags: nuget

I have set up a new nuget feed (company internal feed) and installing packages works without any isuues, but when I try to push a new version for a package, I get a 401 access denied.
What might be the problem?

Edit: To add some more context. I am using a MacOS machine, with a clear text password for the feed since encryption is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding --valid-authentication-types basic in the source config.